# Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError attempting to adapt microposts to Devise/Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pundit

I'm new to Rails and I'm working through Michael Hartl's excellent [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) for a second time, this time I'm trying to adapt the chapter 11 and chapter 12 microposts to a simple Devise/Pundit application I'm working on. I am able to create microposts through the seed file and display them, but I'm getting an authorization error with Pundit when I actually try to create a new post through the site. The error I'm getting is:

```
Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError in MicropostsController#create
```

My Microposts Controller looks like this:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @feed_items = []
      flash[:danger] = "Unable to create micropost!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

I'm thinking that do not have the authorization set up properly for the 'create' action, but I'm not sure exactly how it should be set. I do not have a policy for Pundit for Microposts. I tried adding a simple one but it didn't change anything. I'm learning to put all these pieces together, would someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is one after action filter **verify_authorized** because of which you are getting this error. If you have created a policy for the create action then use that to get rid of the error.